# Navbar items don't highlight in my JS code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to highlight my navbar items for whichever page the user is currently on, the logic seems alright but it doesn't work: Here's my base navbar that is connected to all pages:

```
    <nav class="navbar-container">
        <ul class="navbar-top">
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="{{ url_for('gallery') }}">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="{{ url_for('prices_delivery') }}">Prices and Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="{{ url_for('contacts') }}">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

here's the CSS that makes the current href appear red upon adding a class to  tag:

```
.navbar-top .current {
    color: red;
}
```

and this is the JavaScript code:

```
function navbarHighlight() {
    let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-l');

    navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
        navLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
                navLinks.forEach(navLink => navLink.classList.remove('current'));
                navLink.classList.add('current');
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page is refreshing after a click. If you apply a class on a 'click' event in javascript, the element will have that class, but then the page changes and refreshes as if your javascript never run.

You can do that kind of thing server-side. If you DO want it to be based on the 'click' function that you have that, I recommend using 'sessionStorage' to say which nav button was the last clicked. That way, on page refresh, you can check sessionStorage and highlight the current page. Either that or you can use the `window.location` to determine the current page and highlight from there.

Comment: I think this is more advanced than my skill, can you clarify a little better please?

Comment: Your javascript is running just fine. But after a user clicks a link, the tab goes to a new page. So your javascript ran, it just ran *on the previous page*.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4h5ofkdj/ -- this jsfiddle shows that your code is actually running fine. Clicking a link takes you to a new page, though, so your javascript that you've written isn't running on the new page, it's running on the page you just left.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function navbarHighlight() {
    let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-l');

    navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
        navLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
                navLinks.forEach(navLink => navLink.classList.remove('current'));
                navLink.classList.add('current');
            });
        });
})()
```

```css
.navbar-top .current {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar-container">
        <ul class="navbar-top">
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="#">Prices and Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-l" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: i wish it did :)

Comment: May be you are not invoking it , try to invoke it as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i got it to work with a different method:

```
const currentLocation = location.href;
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const menuLength = menuItem.length;

for (let i=0; i< menuLength; i++) {
    if (menuItem[i].href === currentLocation){
        menuItem[i].className = 'current'
    }
};
```